# How can I set cookies in response object in a NestJS GraphQL application?

Tags: typescript, cookies, graphql, authorization, nestjs

How can I set cookies in response object in a NestJS GraphQL application? Code:

app.module.ts:

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      cors: {
        origin: process.env.ADDRESS,
        credentials: true,
      },
      context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
    }),
```

resolver:

```
 @Mutation(() => token)
  async login(
    @Args("input") input: LoginI,
    @Context() context: GraphQLExecutionContext
  ) {
    const result = await this.authnService.login(input);
    context.res.cookie("authorization", "Bearer " + result.userToken);
    return result;
  }
```

But it doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
console.log(context.res.cookies)
```

returns undefined. Also there are no cookies in browser devtools for my client.

Comment: facing same problem except mine is bit different, cookie is set very well and even persits in playground but for nextjs application, it is set but is lot when I refresh the page, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

For some other people that have issues with receiving cookies in the GraphQL playground, make sure that your playground is configured correctly. By default `request.credentials` is set to `omit`, by switching it to `include` it will start including credentials.

```
const GraphQL = GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  playground: {
    settings: {
      "request.credentials": "include", // Otherwise cookies won't be sent
    }
  },
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
The @Res() decorator is imported from the @nestjs/common, while Response from the express package.

@Post('some-route')
     someHandler(@Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response) {
     # get create refreshToken
     response.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken);
   }
```